# How to move this window?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I just updated Filezilla, but now it moved strangely out of the screen bounds. CF screenshot.

I haven't found any way to make it appear entirely: the upper bar is unreachable and the app edges can only resize it! Anyone knows?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Quit Filezilla, go to `~/.filezilla/` and open `filezilla.xml` with a text editor. Search for `name="Window position and size"`, enter appropriate values and save the file.
On my 1200p x 1920p monitor it looks like this: `<Setting name="Window position and size" type="string">0 10 33 1463 920 </Setting>`

(I don't know what the leading 0 means but 10 is the distance to the left, 33 is the distance to the top, 1463 is the x-size and 920 probably should be the y-size of the window; my real y-size was about 1045)

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803847/set-position-of-window-with-applescript)
You'll need to give the script *access for assistive devices* in, depending on OS version, Accessibility, or Security and Privacy System prefs.

Once that's done, this script should work for you:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Filezilla" to activate
    set position of window 1 of application process "Filezilla" to {100, 100}
end tell
```

Comment: does it implies i have to develop my own Apple Script?

Comment: @Martin -Added script that should work for your App.

Comment: thanks, but there are some quicker ways to do this apparently. +1 anyway for the time you spent on the script ;)